# Pushed icon in toolbar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I put on bevel button in toolbar, set image for this button and uncheck checkbox bordered. How make pushed icon in toolbar like this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to mark your toolbar item as Selectable. Edit your nib file in Xcode, double click the toolbar, click the item in Allowed Toolbar items and, in the Utilities panel, show the Attributes inspector and mark the Selectable checkbox.

Comment: @Niko Have you defined an action for the toolbar item? Otherwise it’ll be disabled if you’re autovalidating it.

Comment: Yes. I defined an action for the toolbar item. This action very simple - (IBAction)openTabs:(id)sender {   
    if ([sender tag]==11111) {
        [mainTabView selectTabViewItemAtIndex:0];}  
    if ([sender tag]==22222) {
        [mainTabView selectTabViewItemAtIndex:1];}
    
    if ([sender tag]==33333) {
        [mainTabView selectTabViewItemAtIndex:2];

Comment: I uncheck checkboxes Autovalidates for each toolbar item. Unfortunately this is have not affect.

Comment: Ok. This is not work for bevel button. I use object "Image toolbar item" and this is work. Thank you Bavarious

Answer (score 3):

Return your item identifiers in the delegate of the toolbar:

```
- (NSArray*)toolbarSelectableItemIdentifiers:(NSToolbar *)toolbar
{
    return _toolbarIdentifiers;
}
```

The toolbar will consider them selectable, so the selected item will be displayed the way you need.

Comment: _toolbarIdentefers - what is it? Pleas show in detail how to do this. I add bevel button in toolbar using drag-n-drop (note code)!

Comment: This is an array with the toolbar item identifiers. The identifiers are strings. Every toolbar item should have a unique one. If you create the toolbar programmatically you return them in [NSToolbarDelegate toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers]. If you use Interface Builder you see them in the inspector when a toolbar item is selected. For example NSToolbarShowColorsItem, NSToolbarShowFontsItem. Assign your own once to your items, like MyToolbarDownloadsItem. Add those identifiers to the array and return them in the toolbars delegate, so the toolbar knows which items are selectable.